# jquery show/hide when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with jQuery. I have a menu page in my app and when I click on a page I want certain divs to be shown and some to be hidden. When I click on a page the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sp").hide();
    $("#fea").hide();
    $("#lib").show();
});
```

only works if I reload the page.

If the document is already loaded when I click on the menu again and go to a different page the same function doesn't work on that page even though I have the same function between script tags on multiple pages.

So in a nutshell whatever page loads first has the function applied. All other pages have to be refreshed before the function is applied. All of my pages are loaded from the menu page.

Does anyone know how to apply the function every time I load a page from my menu page?

I have also tried:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#pageID", function() {
    $("#sp").hide();
    $("#fea").hide();
    $("#lib").show();
});
```

and I have the same issue where the function is only applied when I refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Why you didn't use css for this? It will work even if a javascript will be disabled in the browser settings

Comment: This is going to be wrapped with phonegap so I am not worried about javascript being disabled. I just figured before I abandon jquery for this and use CSS I might get a good explination as to why this is happening in my code. So nobody knows how to do this using jquery? I Have a template for all my pages and I want certain divs to be hidden at first so they only appear when a button is clicked. whats with the down votes?

Comment: Did you add your javascript code in the head section or in the bottom? You should add it in the bottom of body section.

Comment: I have it at the bottom of the body section just after my jquery and jquery mobile script tags. The code I put at the bottom works as long as the app is loaded from the home page. If I go to one of the other pages and hit refresh I have the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to figure out a solution. I am still not sure why the problem was occurring in the first place but I changed my function to this:

```js
 $('body').on('pageinit', function() {
   $("#sp").show();
   $("#fea").hide();
   $("#lib").hide();
  });
```

So thank you to everyone who made snide remarks and down-voted instead of providing a solution, your input was invaluable to my project. ;)